# software not installed after successfull apt-get install in ubuntu subsystem on windows 10

Tags: 16.04, apt, package-management, windows-10, golang

I have installed go via `sudo apt install golang-1.10-go` but I can't execute `go` afterwards since the shell tells me that go is not installed. I tried to install go again. which tells me it is installed and as the original installation did not give me any errors. I am using linux for the past ten years and have to use an ms system and wanted to play around with the ubuntu sub system is behaviour like this expected and normal?

```
rpickhardt@DESKTOP-RQQSLJR:~$ sudo apt install golang-1.10-go
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree     
Reading state information... Done
golang-1.10-go is already the newest version (1.10-1ubuntu1~16.04.1).
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required: libfreetype6
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
rpickhardt@DESKTOP-RQQSLJR:~$ go 
The program 'go' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing: sudo apt install golang-go
```

Comment: Maybe a stupid question, but did you try to install golang-go as suggested?

Comment: You will probably need to file a bug report. Try `which go`

Comment: See https://serverfault.com/questions/894500/program-go-is-currently-not-installed-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: installing like suggested installed go-lang-1.6 behaviour the same. output of which go was empty. but the serverfault link from @Panther was helpful and fixed the issue thank (:

Answer (score 3):

copyied from https://serverfault.com/questions/894500/program-go-is-currently-not-installed-on-ubuntu-16-04 like @Panther said:

Go installed to the /usr/lib directory. So on my computer, this sym link fixed the issue

`sudo ln -s /usr/lib/go-1.9/bin/go /usr/bin/go`